# Tunnel not found

Tags: ngrok

I am using [ngrok 1](https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok) client and server to make a tunnel to localhost.

I run [the script](https://gist.github.com/lyoshenka/002b7fbd801d0fd21f2f) to compile ngrokd and ngrok on server side:

```
NGROK_DOMAIN="my-domain.com"
git clone https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok.git
cd ngrok

openssl genrsa -out rootCA.key 2048
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -subj "/CN=$NGROK_DOMAIN" -days 5000 -out rootCA.pem
openssl genrsa -out device.key 2048
openssl req -new -key device.key -subj "/CN=$NGROK_DOMAIN" -out device.csr
openssl x509 -req -in device.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out device.crt -days 5000

cp rootCA.pem assets/client/tls/ngrokroot.crt
# make clean
make release-server release-client
```

I run server:

```
bin/ngrokd -tlsKey=device.key -tlsCrt=device.crt -domain="$NGROK_DOMAIN" -httpAddr=":8000" -httpsAddr=":8001"
```

Then I download just compiled ngrok to the client.
I create client config:

```
NGROK_DOMAIN="my-domain.com"
echo -e "server_addr: $NGROK_DOMAIN:4443\ntrust_host_root_certs: false" > ngrok-config
```

And run the client:

```
./ngrok -config=ngrok-config 80
```

And it shows that it's online:

```
Tunnel Status                 online                                                                                                                                                 
Version                       1.7/1.7                                                                                                                                                
Forwarding                    http://4f2e0a1e.:8000 -> 127.0.0.1:80                                                                                                                  
Forwarding                    https://4f2e0a1e.:8000 -> 127.0.0.1:80                                                                                                                 
Web Interface                 127.0.0.1:4040                                                                                                                                         
# Conn                        0                                                                                                                                                      
Avg Conn Time                 0.00ms
```

Then I request `http://4f2e0a1e.my-domain.com:8000` expecting it to pass request to my `localhost:80`:

```
curl http://4f2e0a1e.my-domain.com:8000
```

But the response is:

```
Tunnel 4f2e0a1e.my-domain.com:8000 not found
```

On the server I see logs right after curl request:

```
[08:59:15 MSK 2019/02/02] [INFO] (ngrok/log.(*PrefixLogger).Info:83) [pub:1ca51d1c] New connection from myClientIp:63169
[08:59:15 MSK 2019/02/02] [DEBG] (ngrok/log.(*PrefixLogger).Debug:79) [pub:1ca51d1c] Found hostname 4f2e0a1e.my-domain.com:8000 in request
[08:59:15 MSK 2019/02/02] [INFO] (ngrok/log.(*PrefixLogger).Info:83) [pub:1ca51d1c] No tunnel found for hostname 4f2e0a1e.my-domain.com:8000
[08:59:15 MSK 2019/02/02] [DEBG] (ngrok/log.(*PrefixLogger).Debug:79) [pub:1ca51d1c] Closing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, $NGROK_DOMAIN was empty in line

```
bin/ngrokd -tlsKey=device.key -tlsCrt=device.crt -domain="$NGROK_DOMAIN" -httpAddr=":8000" -httpsAddr=":8001"
```

After I set NGROK_DOMAIN=my-domain.com, it started to work properly.

Answer (score 3):

> I got the final and ultimate solution for this issue !

1. Just forget your old account and create a fresh account on
   [Ngrok](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/login)
2. Just add the new auth config to your terminal as per the ngrok
   documentation [here](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started/setup)
3. That's all , now start your tunnel as usual. And it will be working
   fine on WAN.

Comment: It just resolved temporarily and later getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

You can use VMWare workstation instead of oracle virtual box
it will work I m sure.
I was also facing the ngrok tunnel error.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is caused by Ngrok firewalls due to suspicious activities.

You have 3 ways of fixing it

Solution #1: Authenticate/Re-authenticate with your token from ngrok
How to do that?
Steps 1: Go to your ngrok folder location on your terminal
Step 2: Enter: ngrok config add-authtoken your_auth_id

Solution #2: Delete your account and recreate it or create an entirely new account on Ngrok. And don't forget to authenticate your token

Solution #3: If your issue is not solved or you keep getting the same error, reach out to Ngrok support team